# Reading and Writing array of int socket programming, java

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, client-server, serversocket

My client class should take 10 integer input from user and send it to the server. The server should accept these 10 numbers and sort them. It should then send the array back to the client and the client should print them. My client code is:

```
public class TCPClient {
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    int arr[]=new int[10];
    int arrFromServer[]=new int[10];
    BufferedReader inFromUser= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",6786);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(inFromUser.readLine());

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       outToServer.writeInt(arr[i]);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
       arrFromServer[i]=Integer.parseInt(inFromServer.readLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < arrFromServer.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("From Server::"+arrFromServer[i]);
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
}
```

My server code is:

```
public class TCPServer {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int arrFromClient[]=new int[10];
    ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6786);
    while(true){
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            arrFromClient[i]=Integer.parseInt(inFromClient.readLine());
        }
        Arrays.sort(arrFromClient);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrFromClient.length; i++) {
            outToClient.writeInt(arrFromClient[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

When I try to run the code the client keeps on accepting numbers until I terminate the program manually. Ideally after 10 inputs it should go to the server and server should give the sorted array.

What is wrong with the above code. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: write`Int` vs. read`Line`.

Comment: I dint get it :( Which one should I use? I am using readLine to read input from user and writeInt to write it to the server. Is this wrong?

Comment: `writeInt` doesn't write a line. Both methods are explained in the javadocs, I recommend reading them.

Comment: I want to write single integer values. I am using for and passing single values to the server.

Comment: You can't use `readLine()` to read what `writeInt()` writes.

Comment: And can I use vise versa? Can writeInt write what readLine has read?

Comment: That's an interesting philosophical question.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know socket programming and indepth of Java, hence I asked. I am still learning. So if you know you could help out instead of replying sarcastically.

Comment: Read the documentation for the methods and you'll understand  what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply cannot mix `Integer.parseInt(inFromClient.readLine())` with `writeInt()`, you need to use a [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) to write your integers and [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) to read them to make sure that your integers will be properly serialized and deserialized using the same protocol/algorithm.

**Server:**

```
int arrFromClient[]=new int[10];
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6786);
while(true){
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    DataInputStream inFromClient = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        arrFromClient[i] = inFromClient.readInt();
    }
    Arrays.sort(arrFromClient);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrFromClient.length; i++) {
        outToClient.writeInt(arrFromClient[i]);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
int arr[]=new int[10];
int arrFromServer[]=new int[10];
Scanner inFromUser= new Scanner(System.in);
try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",6786)) {
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    DataInputStream inFromServer = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i]=inFromUser.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        outToServer.writeInt(arr[i]);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arrFromServer[i]=inFromServer.readInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < arrFromServer.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("From Server::"+arrFromServer[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively you can use [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to write and read your array as an object using the methods `writeObject` and `readObject` as next:

**Server:**

```
ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6786);
while(true){
    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
    ObjectInputStream inFromClient = new ObjectInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
    ObjectOutputStream outToClient = new ObjectOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    int[] arrFromClient = (int[]) inFromClient.readObject();
    Arrays.sort(arrFromClient);
    outToClient.writeObject(arrFromClient);
}
```

**Client:**

```
int arr[]=new int[10];
Scanner inFromUser= new Scanner(System.in);
try (Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost",6786)) {
    ObjectOutputStream outToServer = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    ObjectInputStream inFromServer = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        arr[i]=inFromUser.nextInt();

    outToServer.writeObject(arr);
    int[] arrFromServer = (int[])inFromServer.readObject();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrFromServer.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("From Server::"+arrFromServer[i]);
    }
}
```